# Pass an instance of a same class in new method and replace "me"

Tags: vb.net

I'm sorry but it's difficult to explain my problem.

I have a class and in the new method, I want to be able to pass an instance of the class - if an instance is passed, this instance should be used (replace 'me').

An example...

```
Public Class DataConnection
    Implements IDisposable

    Public Property SqlCnn As SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Private _isNewInstance As Boolean

    Public Sub New()
        _isNewInstance = True
        SqlCnn = New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    End Sub


    Public Sub New(dc As DataConnection)
        _isNewInstance = False
        Me = dc ' <- this is not valid
    End Sub


#Region "IDisposable Support"
    Private disposedValue As Boolean

    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
            End If

            If _isNewInstance Then
                SqlCnn.Close()
                SqlCnn.Dispose()
                SqlCnn = Nothing
            End If
            ' Do my clean up code
        End If
        disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

Then I want to be able to create new instances like this:

```
Dim dc As New DataConnection
Dim dc2 As New DataConnection(dc)
```

I need it to support "using" statement, since my real class implements iDisposable and I need to do one thing if no instance was passed and another thing is an instance was passed in the new method. So I can't use singleton.

Comment: Your initial suggestion makes no sense.  `Me` refers to the current object so how could you replace the current object inside the current object?  What you say you actually want to achieve would just be done with a "copy constructor".  Look it up.  There's no magic to it.  You simply copy property values from one instance to the other.  You can even access private members in that context.

Comment: Why you want set `Me` point to the same object you provided, instead use already created object?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear ... I've updated my sample to reflect my real problem.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ... well my real class is properly near 100 properties, so it's a tedious to copy each property ... there must be a smarter solution.

Comment: You can use Reflection to copy any number of properties using a loop.  `Type.GetProperties`, `PropertyInfo.GetValue` and `PropertyInfo.SetValue`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, where to start?

Me refers to the **inside** of the current object.
Such as a Form, Class, or other Object.
Me is shorthand and doesn't work like a pointer in C.

If you really want to copy properties of two classes, you should either implement a .Copy Sub or do it outside of the class.

Have you tried

```
Public Function CopyAnObject(ByVal Source as Object) as Object
      CopyAnObject = Source
End Function
```

I'm confused what the use case for this could be, but seems like you're trying to hack something which isn't worth hacking?

Can the OP provide any more information on **what s/he wants to achieve**?

If you're really desperate to hack it, convert the whole Class into an IO.MemoryStream and hack it from there.